# Ways to mount a Sd card / Usb drive in a different location

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu

I was wondering if I can mount a sd card or usb stick in a different location rather than /media 
If there is a way to do this please tell me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like (assuming your desired directory is `~/usb` and the current mount point is `/media/xcy/CCD3-9E9D`):

```
$ mkdir ~/usb
$ sudo mount --bind /media/xcy/CCD3-9E9D ~/usb
```

then you can use both of these two directories, or here is another way (assuming your device name is `/dev/sdb1`)

```
$ umount /dev/sdb1           # unmount if it's already mounted
$ mkdir ~/usb                # make dir if it isn't already exist
$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 ~/usb
```

then you can use `~/usb`.

You can find out your device name and mount point with `mount` (without any options or arguments), in my case, they are `/dev/sdb1` and `/media/xcy/CCD3-9E9D/` when I insert my usb drive.